# Why is a class 2 medical not valid in Canada?

Tags: medical, canada

Upon reviewing the requirements for the Recreational Pilot Permit and Private Pilot License in Canada, I see that only class 1, 3 and 4 medicals are approved.

Are EASA class 2 medicals not valid in Canada at all?

Comment: I believe it's only for ATC.  Could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The Cat 2 medical in Canada is only for Flight Engineers, Navigators (once upon a time) and Air Traffic Controllers.  https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/publications/tp13312-2-menu-2331.htm

Comment: It would seem that category 2 medicals are different from ICAO class 2. Is the CAR aligned with ICAO regulations here?